# Work and depth of DAG - problem in understanding exam question

Tags: parallel-computing

I have some problems understanding the following 2 question from an exam last year, which I am preparing for this week in Parallel Programming.

[image: DAG]

Determine the Work -> $W(n) = 7$ (#vertices)

Determine the Depth -> $D(n) = 4$ (longest path)

Determine average parallelism -> $\frac{W(n)}{D(n)} = 7/4$

Ok, now the 2 questions, which I have problems with:

*What is the minimum number of processors that are needed to achieve depth?*

For this question I only have a vague idea: $infinity$? Because if we use Brents theorem:

$$\frac{W(n)}{p} <=T_p(n) <= \frac{W(n)}{p} + D(n)$$

maybe we can achive depth? I am not sure.

*What is the number of processors larger or equal to 2 that achieves the maximum efficiency for this problem?*

That should be relatively easy, but I am not sure, how I should calculate the Speedup? I know several formulas, but I do not know how to calculate the fraction, which must be run sequentially ($S=\frac{p}{1+(p-1)f)}$) or the execution times.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

$D = 5$ (and is not a funtion of $n$ here) and goes $1 - 2 -
4 - 5 - 6$.

> What is the minimum number of processors that are needed to achieve
> depth?

It clearly cannot be achieved with one processor, but here is a
schedule that achieves it using two processors:

| Time | $P_1$ | $P_2$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |  |
| 3 | 4 |  |
| 4 | 5 | 7 |
| 5 | 6 |  |

Since $T_2 = D$, speedup is simply $S_2 = T_1/T_2 = W/D = 7/5$.